# how to remove shadow-root (user-agent)

Tags: html, css, asp.net, dom

I wrote in html is,

`<asp:TextBox ID="txtComment" runat="server"  onkeyup="loadValues(this,250)" MaxLength="250"></asp:TextBox>`

But Chrome Browser shows

```
    <input name="BirthdayWish1$txtComment" type="text" maxlength="250" 
id="BirthdayWish1_txtComment" onkeyup="loadValues(this,250)">

    #shadow-root(user-agent)
    <div id="inner-editor"></div>
    </input>
```

I want to remove this **#shadow-root(user-agent)**  
because input field shows green color segments.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error this is comes from external css class.
I have given green color image like this this is the case to my problem.

```
input[type=text],input[type=password],textarea{color:#626262;display:inline-block;background:#FFF url(../images/forminput.gif) top left repeat-x;border-radius:2px;width:100%;border:1px solid #CCC;height:17px;margin:2px 0;padding:2px 1px;}
```